# Why can't property map be read?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to iterate through an array of objects to display all items of a certain name. For some reason my `this.props.list.items` cannot be read. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code for item.js

```
import React from "react";

class Item extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.props.list.items}</div>
      )
  }
}

export default Item
```

The code for horizontalscroll.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ScrollMenu from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
import './horizontalscroll.css';
import Item from './Item';

// list of items
const list = [
  {
    name: "Brands",
    items: ["1", "2", "3"]
  },
  {
    name: "Films",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  },
  {
    name: "Holiday Destination",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  }
];
// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({ text, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="menu-item"
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};

// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = (list) => list.map(el => {
  const { name } = el;

  return (
    <MenuItem
      text={name}
      key={name}
    />
  );
});


const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
    >{text}</div>
  );
};


const ArrowLeft = Arrow({ text: '<', className: 'arrow-prev' });
const ArrowRight = Arrow({ text: '>', className: 'arrow-next' });

class HorizantScroller extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: 0
  };

  onSelect = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: key });
  }








  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(list, selected);

    return (
      <div className="HorizantScroller">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
          arrowRight={ArrowRight}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />
      <div>{this.props.items.map((item) => {
        return <Item item={item}/>
      })}
      </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default HorizantScroller;
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside Item, you should access it like this

```
<div>{this.props.item}</div>
```

Because when rendering Item, you did `<Item item={item}/>`

Comment: This should do the job.

Comment: @JonathanPein there are a lot of issues with your code, my answer only answers a portion of it. for example, you are doing: `const menu = Menu(...)` this should not be dong, you need to do: `<Menu ... />` menu returns a react element that you are passing as data prop to a component

Comment: I am confused as to where you mean inside item? please could you clarify

Comment: You should also assign a unique key to each Item component you render. Inside your map you should  `return <Item key={/*uniquieKey*/} item={item}/>`